URLDAY API Not working according to published docs
I am trying to use URLDAY's API to do anything, but any call returns an error, weather it is from Python code, or from CURL.
Example:
curl --location \
    --request POST 'https://www.urlday.com/api/v1/links' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer MYKEY' \
    --data-urlencode 'url=www.mysite.com'

And getting

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><style>*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#313131;font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji}body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh;min-height:100vh}.main-content{margin:8rem auto;max-width:60rem;padding-left:1.5rem}@media (width <= 720px){.main-content{margin-top:4rem}}.h2{font-size:1.5rem;font-weight:500;line-height:2.25rem}@media (width <= 720px){.h2{font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.5rem}}#challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;padding-left:34px}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{background-color:#222;color:#d9d9d9}}</style><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="390"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div class="h2"><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></noscript></div></div><script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '3',cZone: "www.urlday.com",cType: 'managed',cRay: '8e08331dcca21acd',cH: 'HyW8MnqMqm6YWgrOmNPmohplrASP4fwSME_wvXU3lJU-1731264327-1.2.1.1-GiHFy7gK1YR1LgIRs9XsNTuIyhzpPt2ymtCIA81sVVAvQHst77aZKRq7k_TF6t8w',cUPMDTk: "\/api\/v1\/links?__cf_chl_tk=uY1iQn0S0a87ut2HpiKE.FZ4k_gLv8HwOxLHCt__Knw-1731264327-1.0.1.1-sg9FwzkoXlF75yOeYU7xDtEpVSKZkkHFqhu1y5V0Q1E",cFPWv: 'b',cITimeS: '1731264327',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '390000',cTplC: 0,cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK: "",fa: "\/api\/v1\/links?__cf_chl_f_tk=uY1iQn0S0a87ut2HpiKE.FZ4k_gLv8HwOxLHCt__Knw-1731264327-1.0.1.1-sg9FwzkoXlF75yOeYU7xDtEpVSKZkkHFqhu1y5V0Q1E",md: "KKYy.WDOpN3Nbh2hchr.5_65FIeP2MXY1SwLe7D0i9g-1731264327-1.2.1.1-8rDviJPWKQZ5GHZ2CJEs76rsOIWvKcleM6GXN_czTDntvOpBG15TYHn.r1BlH6CpuH.qNNZZLHgxeq19wVsLNnhQEPGMDA6f_zAhPQYB6_SElooCBnQzh1JK5SbQJWkTBzUwyaiDwdmCwi7dvUF35SXcwViWI1kxb.YIeY07hhNv7UA9MW3V81KcqjXl__pFkCjsXpuswYWqbtCTY10v4eelrErdByJfcNRhWK0u4dL4rPGVFPwllV3mnh9urfMUNcg5R_7Btw5spRXkT7GVcSUxZguJpfCawNnZY.8HZbBU5Lr7drk1LdItmWHWvijeWRwXF_3R7TySwGiFwu7yuVgijvk.qUnT2mP6EakO03TL7ytUiTgFWbpHd.VL1ziFqu5vDEDdhSzMuPhRNUOmDn1v7Lb145D6UoF0XY85jSHxEvFOtTiMNnVdQsUvXOx9heoZij9AoaVVmqXQGchwI5YsEXu9WxKBgpmr_7GP7ouA61aO2B5tsFnFFeinNUkZOsctRvw7wN_HFlWRCXvX3H4wvD_Z0aqakydWZxhq5OkJj0y78x_J3p4_YRnwO4PUGQ0vdvYuoK3Dq8nzZHmx9RnOX1FkA.Eg3HA5RZ.ijv3bNRIJOPDXO3irXk.9V5FGpM2FK4xb0FzOFJuzPffZQGhAHSNRxixMffItxaT2Yt.RKSxAbLVAy7AiKGTiJPWaO7xAWoy9mphqAjO6iA5X.jPIkvwYxmEQqpDlgjO62HMKzvbXc.kJ5WZtMcCrZJ4r7SYThwm5kxzT0RH.N6LTN8eXxbtE6zkkXWMDoRZ5yew69LX4_c9RVcx74VTrcLBERIGQRgcrjaYX7OpWcw58fdRkKnUtj2MhdK3WQ8sX_.YZyLBAVUOYDzvYF0CJY2LIOvlP7MZLYkr1s92svbTrehOmoGz8g_e4.QfHUUnZKycK8lKKXOSkWhqAFg6i9mmNWSpoqI6yMMRYSUKx0JmrqSFfOK8MA9no5FJcQC_mF3QnCnHR3mllBmpWGJgPpcexbTfBFi1FSj6G08BUtgR.px6Elmn_9EzhgvRk8NPTUILAh7iFqmQUpcPNpx3HuY53p8Ny1atXd6EAHJvH14HHew0W70IN0297X_r1c7AZXpV019eLLjez6694UKhhfp_7b0UA3sMeBdF8sXnx01ixU4b8XPcbk9aF468HWWE6OXP0QrewxztouEzJIV1Nzlqv0Zz61Ooyc3lmW9bSeMqQteq8F211Fczcrx8NTBB4xflEqRzuvPsGahxwop6nkIHkMQpk.o.d6kKLzb_JimsNpYHDpICedYFPaOW2lComFHBlSUeolgEwKc4.XjXfHS7afjE84Jm0PvOOmAg.HOhC33XbUxml8Ta4rH4FjWzrslao6ZRoELPvk9BPXXdn7DT4KbunWH12WLwDQhRq.GQcQDck38IETL.8bwMzcHUZyuTUTJP.8E65jljcmc__FO1tOEhe1ZaUN3BpcLtWJo4FiXuq6oZEXgu3rX1E.9msY.nLTgKGj_wHcMZsxPjwqOPKV90zcb35FH54dYyaNCND9US9wMWLOsgW8jnQmJwONJAciSrrSyk9EwL3GKi5XJvhjfeqTfvpnluimLMOg.dVmbdEWF0KxdF5Pz5PniQdarayu_mzr0n.HZjfhEqwvkAuj_7sjnVJilNYSq4cg2S2QP0eTxuUh_xN718WVpfYicJMWyYqZPRTBGRmP_x.oXmqxcCeU5gRLiix.puYsHR74N36kWQ72ddVBv0T9aK6UO2VhX55E3btcQV1TYvZ2HS3uBJ55vn_s7isLRemAbs3oeVoDl5tEIBfISv6EAp0Yw5vdNbVoa9lBsrbuyagIOFyhxJ5PTubzo6GarQlZh6Tus42pF4Vp_G_u5L5IRcKeWnt4XhfKBsUwu_dW855QTyCr5dZkJvKFiBKnf.ebph1tBjOThnuCHcM3Fy7SgMwTp8nTiXWOmX8gMPDxkMSwt7RT8oMZJZmtWfkSyCJpl2K2mItIGq8H5cVK6El0Uekv1ketAGWTdto3YEDnOeWCy3jo8howaOM3Ig2cp4AeNwT3MtzFa4rEa_5nk5Qs7I__ek",mdrd: "s.YaFQ_AbmGHujee.CTyXKeuFoYXBRWMds.XzBkGH7U-1731264327-1.2.1.1-_zIQ.47khGTYN6ojbTccAEvixHeqKpN4TUrnkydBF9uZwm_FDJCcXdKqOypPGTFOCFe.29l5jeXIuOdwOhxt6sS4gTYxBxkRzKYJG7gbq0raaEOZmZokW5v7qi1_q84FpSx4UZcEBNRzmRxEyDbEYylSBIuoBJH2aPD3kDtAtNfLyfdo1sXkiWBU78o3hV.hyieGbpnq5e7JbXINH_swuy1hKGFF6jNe6V2.m38otesxpl6quOlDDPHSfd4oPZDv7P_6OjwYYBRNdtgjrjbRUrNamDOUR_rU5.WTnd8Mo_Z2v16o9ovFA7vIpxnXi91lhGUKK6J8xFUhYjafbGhm1SQOOLciN6h3uJJyPzu_UFOd5u7o7izKbA3T0XaZyCpC1XgMQcb5WATLv_EQ5D6xSwdKu3ust9gMgosB_x0LH1iYFEsY58H5rUD5MuA3nmDbrGy5XvQC0KnH2EwloETFbtIG7XgjHAxUgLXeEqT6.IZZpjTH9cxf6snajfllx8qvcuVCgFSmoEw1F9SUzZZSwewTKlI6mcatPI57.TAtkI1Zk8CqJoIpZvMguMvopnAISYrBfwrFmuWFg60XYCyVQSUpyEvNOvkpj2YZCsETMzq8hKh0eFEtONXFxsLYRzuwYsIq4uSV59nCXL7Djay6uIcqWFuu_BhtpK6.RF3HKjAsK0JorIAY5cdIAatdaVL2dWBgg49cqRRrv6QC.lnf7sF3pWSnswbwXYYJqR4dEshOIVZbMVMgrp469R57kdCetOrW9rvg6WadAx.Jrb1diuiDfOiAo8I8krZfT2fGWamdV2Ddq_q_oy60_jjFLJZvf8_OZ340.TcoM107p8w7di349sUCzyxEVcn1WjlpzkbNILTaqXPUHQFaNxj6J27B0OaIbA42U7.X9273_C1i8IbDO7tgvbz8z7VQKxHMArOmBgmq0CjFmXiQUQ0GaOhXjwkKaboiR23x.l3J_CLIM7K25Ispeb7HBeNVBNXGxp1j6PwkMn9csstdEqbk0XtvIC_C6jL8.IoPjabtri53eeVK7A00SPAbmg1WHm1DJF_MRv8rnNWtXneNp0MWkoepbdL.h7xoejwfrazgIKvUtYHlSORSdzcaIW5HobDnrW7lIFMNyPbikUuVhJJlgvXifrBr_VIXTWLfw5OLtLw94Cd6LRoFDTpYIKlCTME0C_A_AmQzbKynvKhkEEFueed9P2xUvFCxKsgXHAA9b9sO5nxCYjRjOBy1ak7gZ74PDt4XAJY9Nxj8aDjiDUxCtbdUHiVUwMRAaVuiAcbRbQt5GH.PA3NzSQZLcmYZT8tMi21VmK.WEqYBg8XeVpHtnD.ykaGvHst67uoIa4O.bU5gHzTsbQeEE0TWpoyjm1cK25WuMyiYw8WPRqOE3o7mHcpzjJyT8J76C3SbPsJZ9bklsMqr.PZmfcjScqFlhNIoHUvPGkbEKrFF0YJi7kOTxfeyZr_iOR2icr5hiIvXku0Js0s_Q9RVBe.X.b1wA_vBFj0KEYLkSaMnNRX6l9DsopYxaSS1JnaPciMZU2Yz9uFbOU1iAl7_enz2__Cwzul881wK2z.FeYVFJhl.f9i3H7zgsgIto6iPnFmZSGiZcWgbvldHrQrJJs5SvKoxCutTTbqPpw2Ms5dP0pSOaNTBIMoYcq_DIJPNY8vLZN02Ah7rcuXUHSP_J9kl1Iee.7RrK0VgZ5wX_s0uyMKdCF.ejsbyKU4aND875csYp2wYpKBW.8B23hmVrqyCIDDIUhVOKBEw1U9htRr3rOm3MRD8q1BXAwUBe0twlsTqvUtleRsQ8ykZytJf2QHXi5sUDshYqdd6Ufgx_kqJqDgat1nqaJFo_8D.25GkNqAaQX1MJH_2e3UGAScF0ClqBAkqMx5i0Thxc_ecPUe8jkDpX0vRoH7He2Q9AERVyJI3kQZ4wm4U2hMpmY5ApuyaEw5jSo7AWmPkahlwGZ2YNGZAjXuOiEVDKWLbHM4hN6Jjjk_FdlNAFEQfmP4k0tdV._Z_Wb8Vq9mJyh3XeovjycTa7Nyluy9EinmswwoTATlJ6DqrR5Y8oldJRYm2OovG22dR9f2R.utud8fLOxMiPoAAJbuMkhR_3vtXHidyBoeuA0VQ1Oy9yl2GelO0jiGYlRD17HwehhzeoVRGV6wkzdmX7w4XoC2kncvoBeTV2jno9Erd0JQEDK77lpsMjVH.CBkC92dznKAMQXHQVdl6Avu1fUSNb6C0CWGyCdvMMB1lSu2q.KhCAoqndPEtjsseTTLr4n47nLTdckWHjU7FcO0oQXRLj5n71Igq_NFwoJajXchLwP27Ao7hFuJw05QKSpL1KajV0KUkN8d072ALiql5JpeCyyIuYISy8TEIi_sjtC784cDkY3P4EM._sE3DGWQiIobSJGx9nq1.aWnAzZrbLNYlR4YM9XhkoW2B6tPbCfVyvo4m0d3.dg1BYgBjOTyV5UP1lF0"};var cpo = document.createElement('script');cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=8e08331dcca21acd';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceState(null, null, "\/api\/v1\/links?__cf_chl_rt_tk=uY1iQn0S0a87ut2HpiKE.FZ4k_gLv8HwOxLHCt__Knw-1731264327-1.0.1.1-sg9FwzkoXlF75yOeYU7xDtEpVSKZkkHFqhu1y5V0Q1E" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload = function() {history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);}}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());</script></body></html>

Trying with Python:
url = "https://www.urlday.com/api/v1/links"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eVnWvTBAD0Aai8w8YaAoopAgc3RZmRVEtmedYKNDZCIMg5Yv1Rbh7jTE77xf"
}
data = {
    "url": "www.mysite.com"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

# Print the response
print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response JSON:", response.json())

Getting
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/noams/src/personal_website/backend/services/UrlShortener.py", line 55, in <module>
    print("Response JSON:", response.json())
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I tried a bunch of useless workarounds not even worthy of mentioning.

I am clearly missing something. What's the correct way to access their API?

Your target app is protected by Cloudflare so you have to add your user-agent header along with cookie (I don't know why they didn't mention it in their documentation, also www.example.com is an invalid URL format, you have to add scheme http/https)
How to find your cookie?:
Firefox --> visit site --> inspect element --> network tab --> reload --> click one your target app request and copy the cookie value from the request header
Do the same for User-Agent
code:
import requests

url = "https://www.urlday.com/api/v1/links"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eVnWvTBAD0Aai8w8YaAoopAgc3RZmRVEtmedYKNDZCIMg5Yv1Rbh7jTE77xf",
    "Cookie": "YOUR COOKIE IS HERE", #add cookie value
    "User-Agent": "YOUR USER-AGENT HEADER IS HERE" #add user-agent header value
}
data = "url=https://www.example.com" #www.example.com is an invalid URL format, so add scheme too https/http

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

# Print the response
print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response JSON:", response.json())

Output:
Status Code: 201
Response JSON: {'data': {'id': 'peg2Pw3o', 'alias': 't7qza', 'url': 'https://www.example.com', 'short_url': 'https://urlday.cc/t7qza', 'title': 'Example Domain', 'target_type': None, 'country_target': None, 'platform_target': None, 'language_target': None, 'rotation_target': None, 'last_rotation': None, 'disabled': None, 'privacy': None, 'privacy_password': False, 'password': False, 'expiration_url': None, 'expiration_clicks': None, 'clicks': None, 'user_id': 5071, 'space': '', 'domain': None, 'pixels': '', 'ends_at': None, 'created_at': '2024-11-15T20:56:58.000000Z', 'updated_at': '2024-11-15T20:56:58.000000Z'}, 'status': 200}


thanks. Do any of the cookie/user agent reset? I need this automatic, can't be doing this manually over and over (so the "find cookie in firefox seems a bit odd to me). Also, I will run this in some Serverless API server, so I don't have firefox there. How to find these strings in that case?

hey, your local browser's cookie and user-agent header should do the job!
